# Monitor Internet in/out request and change it (c#)

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to monitor all internet request/response which send from all browser and other application and change them.
some way that I test:

```
            // Create a listener.
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

        // Add the prefixes.
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/"); //hamid was *:80
        listener.Start();
        textBox3.Text = "listening...";//Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request.
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        // Obtain a response object.
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        // Construct a response.
        string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        // You must close the output stream.
        output.Close();
        listener.Stop();
```

Comment: without any proxy settings, or any changes of browser just with socket programming like iPig

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your other application support proxies like the browsers do, a good option might be to use the [Fiddler Core library](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/) and create a proxy server that all requests are passed through.

http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/

Comment: without any proxy settings, or any changes of browser just with socket programming like iPig